# Eager Loading Optimization in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, query-optimization

I have a product that has_many Variants. And a variant belongs to a product. I want to display the name of the product(which can be found in Product) and the price and quantity(which can be found in Variants).

```
Product table:
 -id
 -title
 -description

Variants table:
 - id
 - is_active(boolean)
 - price
 - quantity
 - product_id
```

This is how the table looks like. And this is my attempt

```
  def index

    @products =Product.all
    @display = []
    @products.each do |product|
      @children = product.variants.where(is_active: true).order(:price).
                                   select(:id,:price,:quantity).first

      if @children.present?
      @display << {
                   id: product.id,
                    title: product.title,
                    description: product.description,
                    price:  @children.price,
                    quantity:  @children.quantity,
                    variant_id:  @children.id
                  }
      end
    end

    @display = Kaminari.paginate_array(@display).page(params[:page])

  end
```

I need to optimize this to the maximum. Which brings me to my first question. How can I optimize this better .
And my 2nd question why when I do @products = Product.all.includes(:variants) it will actually increase the loading time instead of lowering it since I do get the variants for every product in that iteration over the whole @products array(so it should count as an N+1, I get products for each product I get variants)?
Is spliting my array of @products in 4 and making 4 threads populate display a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't using the eager loaded data which is why adding includes is slowing things down - it's just extra work.

In general if you call query methods ( `where`, `order`, etc) rails can't use the eager loaded data. Instead you can make a new association:

```
has_many :active_variants,  -> { where(is_active: true).order(:price) }, class_name: "Variant"
```

Then eager load and use this association instead of the variants association.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I have one request please. Could you demonstrate how I can use :active_variants relationship with include because I try it like @products = Product.all.includes(:active_variants) and i get uninitialized constant Product::ActiveVariant

Comment: Oops - left out a crucial bit!

Comment: Well it really works. But it increases the time again :)) from 1.800ms to 4,600ms . But i can't say no to your answer

Comment: Make sure you drop the select too.

Comment: I sadly did that before you told me :(

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as;

```
def index
  @display = Varient.joins(:product).where(is_active: true).order(:price).select('products.id as id, products.title, products.description, price, quantity, variants.id as variant_id')
end
```

Comment: I really tried using it that way and rails said who the f is "price" no such column (I added variants.price in the select)

Comment: plus it produces this query SELECT products.id as id, products.title, products.description,variants. price, variants.quantity, variants.id as variant_id FROM "products" WHERE "products"."is_active" = 't'  ORDER BY "products"."price" ASC (no join)

Comment: @display = Product.select('products.id as id, products.title, products.description, variants.price, variants.quantity, variants.id as variant_id').joins(:variants).where("variants.is_active = ?", 'true').order("variants.price") this is executed but returns nothing .

Comment: This will change the result - eg products with no variants won't be returned